# Converting Dataframe in Required Html Table format in R

Tags: css, r, html-table, kable, kableextra

I have below mentioned dataframe:

```
structure(list(Month = c("May-17", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "Apr-17", 
"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "Mar-17", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), 
    No = c(75L, 10L, 15L, 12L, 18L, 20L, 75L, 9L, 12L, 10L, 19L, 
    25L, 72L, 8L, 13L, 9L, 18L, 24L), `Inc_%` = c("0.00%", "11.11%", 
    "25.00%", "20.00%", "-5.26%", "-20.00%", "4.17%", "12.50%", 
    "-7.69%", "11.11%", "5.56%", "4.17%", "0.00%", "0.00%", "0.00%", 
    "0.00%", "0.00%", "0.00%"), Total = c("34,500", "1,000", 
    "1,500", "2,500", "4,500", "25,000", "36,500", "1,100", "1,200", 
    "2,200", "4,000", "28,000", "35,000", "1,000", "1,100", "2,000", 
    "3,900", "27,000"), `Inc_%2` = c("-5.48%", "-9.09%", "25.00%", 
    "13.64%", "12.50%", "-10.71%", "4.29%", "10.00%", "9.09%", 
    "10.00%", "2.56%", "3.70%", "0.00%", "0.00%", "0.00%", "0.00%", 
    "0.00%", "0.00%"), Mean = c("28,200", "800", "1,200", "2,200", 
    "4,000", "20,000", "6,47,289", "7,57,991", "5,18,091", "6,95,407", 
    "1,68,428", "9,10,521", "7,38,687", "5,87,810", "8,05,300", 
    "7,67,826", "1,84,875", "11,73,866"), A = c(56L, 11L, 15L, 
    19L, 10L, 1L, 50L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 56L, 11L, 15L, 
    19L, 10L, 1L), Sum_A = c("27,800", "800", "1,000", "2,000", 
    "4,000", "20,000", "32,500", "1,000", "1,000", "2,000", "3,500", 
    "25,000", "31,800", "800", "1,000", "1,500", "3,500", "25,000"
    ), B = c(19L, 5L, 9L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 25L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    16L, 5L, 9L, 2L, 0L, 0L), Sum_B = c("6,700", "200", "500", 
    "500", "500", "5000", "4,000", "100", "200", "200", "500", 
    "3,000", "3,200", "200", "100", "500", "400", "2,000"), `%` = c("20.00%", 
    "12.00%", "22.50%", "10.50%", "11.50%", "16.20%", "20.20%", 
    "10.20%", "15.50%", "14.20%", "18.20%", "18.00%", "15.00%", 
    "10.20%", "13.20%", "14.50%", "15.00%", "11.20%"), Day = c(12L, 
    10L, 8L, 7L, 5L, 12L, 10L, 8L, 9L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 10L, 8L, 9L, 
    7L, 8L, 8L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -18L
))
```

I want to convert it into html table format exact like below or if any nice format you guys can suggest:
[image]

I am not able to convert font size of A,B,C,D and E less than 1 the normal size (Normal font size = 11) and italic and bordering as shown in the format.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `kable` from `knitr` and the `kableExtra`-package for this:

```
kable(my_df, "html", table.attr = 'style = "border-collapse: collapse;"') %>% 
  # for left alignment
  kable_styling(position = "left") %>%  
  # header row in orange
  row_spec(0, background = "orange") %>% # header row in orange
  # All rows equal A, B, C, D, or E are italic and one font size smaller
  row_spec(which(my_df$Month %in% LETTERS[1:5]), font_size = 10, italic = T) %>% 
  # All other rows are yellow and bold
  row_spec(which(!my_df$Month %in% LETTERS[1:5]), background = "yellow", bold = T) %>% 
  # All cells get a border
  row_spec(0:nrow(my_df), extra_css = "border: 1px solid black;")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank...the boarders are missing and when i run the code my all rows became yellow except for the first row. And since i am not aware of this package can you please tell me how to add caption.

Comment: I am using these html table to e-mail using `library(mailR)` and in email the alignment of the table is center i want it to be left aligned.

Comment: You ran the code and got a different output than I got? Did you use the exact same example you provided? For modifying th solution you might want to have a look at the documentation of [kableExtra](https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_html.html)

Comment: Yes...i am using same example dataframe.

Comment: Understand the error, you have identified other 5 rows by `row_spec(which(my_df$Month %in% LETTERS[1:5])` considering that there are only 1 letter but in my original dataframe the letter are vary from 3 to 13.

Comment: I have used: `row_spec(which(my_df$Month %in% Word("Week1")), font_size = 10, italic = T) %>% 
  # All other rows are yellow and bold
  row_spec(which(!my_df$Month %in% ("Week1")), background = "yellow", bold = T) %>% `

Comment: for first condition it worked but for second condition (i.e `row_spec(which(!my_df$Month %in% Word ("Week1"))` its not working.

Comment: Please help here...didn't find any way out.

Comment: did it...:) can you just help me with to bold first column and add caption above first row and add boarder.

Comment: Bold the first column, Please help me with the caption and bordering only.

Comment: The border is already added with the last line, or what is missing? You can add a caption with specifiying `caption = "Your caption"` in the `kable` call (first row)

Comment: I have already tried `caption = " "` but it is coming above the table not as a part of table like in merge format with table.